# What do you think of uniGUI, the framework for creating web applications and win32 applications at the same time?

Tags: delphi, web-applications

I've just been redirected by a firend on [the uniGUI website](http://www.unigui.com/). In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022378/raudus-vs-extpascal-delphi-web-developement-alternatives-that-use-extjs) I asked about a comparison between Raudus and ExtPascal.

Now this unigui seems to be an alternative to Raudus, that moreover has the advantage of allowing you to compile the win32 exe at the same time with the same source code (of course if you limit yourself to use only uniGUI approved UI components).

I think this is amazing, even if this idea at a first sight willnot make happy all the web apps purists, but in my opionion having this kind of tool is great.

There are many (even small) applications, that can benefit for this code once, get a double UI.

Anyway which are your feelings about this? Do you think it has a future?

**ADDITIONAL NOTE: In order not to start a general discussion please try to answer by mentioniong uniGUI specifically, not only a general answer. Thanks.**

Comment: Creating apps that are the worst of both worlds?

Comment: To be honest to myself I must admit that I am looking at uniGUI for the webapp only. My real comment is: having to create an app that has a simple UI (not necessarly a simple app) we can charge our customers 50% more for having both win32 and web app, while writing it only once...

Comment: @Marco van de Voort: Would you like to come over to my place? You know, I have this app I really like. But I suppose, it could be much better, if it were compiled for my specific hardware and software configuration and optimized for my prefered screen resolution. Also, could you please install two versions, one for my german, and the other one for my english keyboard? So I don't have the worst of both input experiences? I'm asking you, because everybody else in this world is so busy with this "portability"-thing, but you don't seem to care ;)

Comment: @back2dos: Portability should be about keeping the codebase as portable as possible without functionality, not the other way around. Mutilating the experience is no solution

Comment: There is this "kitto" web framework that works just like UniGUI but open-source and free.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I started developing uniGUI (or whatever name it may adopt in future) around two years ago. Since then it has evolved a lot. Initial version was based on VCL for the Web. With addition of **ExtPascal** and **Ext JS** it has become a very advanced tool to develop Web apps based on Delphi.

**uniGUI** simply defines itself as a Web Application Development framework. The concept of **Web Application** has been controversial since its first inception. Some people claim that Web is stateless but applications are statefull, one should not mix these two. However, nowadays with an increasing demand for web applications such notions only remain as a philosophical point of view.

More and more people want to access their desktop apps from the internet. Companies want their local accounting software to be accessible to other branches. A security company wants a web gateway for their access control software. These are all examples for the increasing demand for web apps.

We can consider uniGUI as an abstraction layer for Delphi VCL controls which extends them to the Web. Like all other abstraction layers it helps developer to focus on application logic rather than the development tool itself. It tries to fully integrate the RAD approach into Delphi based Web development.

Dual nature of uniGUI is simply a plus. I'm referring to its ability to deploy same application to both web and desktop using same codebase. This feature maybe useful for some developers but useless for others and it can be completely ignored by those who focus on Web development only.

As for the scalability, the best target for uniGUI and other similar tools seems to be the intranet where the number of clients are predictable and connection speed is a non-issue.

That said, nothing prevents developers from developing web apps that target the internet. At end it is all **Ext JS** on the client side and Delphi event handlers on the server side. It all depends on how smart you design your app and how efficient you manage your resources. If each of your sessions consumes 10 MB of memory then you're likely to run out of memory very soon.

In conclusion, this framework will have a group of users which will find it best for their needs. There is no black or white here only big gray areas. Like any other tool it depends on the company, the particular project and the available deployment options to see if it is the right tool for you or not.

Comment: Of course there is no correct answer to a "what do you think of..." question, anyway these comments are from the uinGUI creator, so they are not our guesses, but the original plans! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Web applications are **very** different from GUI ones. Mixing two approaches for something
more serious then simple form or several buttons I think is just wrong.

Comment: Even if in general you are right, I don't agree with you (and since I was expecting this as the first question I wrote about "web apps purists"). Not all web applications are used by 1 million users, in that case I agree with you 100%. But in many, many cases, there is the need of web apps, just because users access from different platforms, and from different locations. In those cases the UI is not necessarly super simple. I users are not too many I think win32 + webapp can make sense (in same scenarios, of course). Then of course if one allows to retrieve 1000000 records in a webapp...

Comment: @user193655 You asked about the opinion, I give it. Otherwise I don't see a point in the question.

Comment: Ok, i will modify my question to clarify that I'd like to have an answer uniGUI related, not general only. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the UniGUI idea is a great one. But I think that Embarcadero is the one that should offer that as one more option for developers instead of a independent one. Delphi developers always wanted an easy way to create web applications, and sincerely WebBroker is very poor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what do you think of it?

Answer (score 1):

*Anyway which are your feelings about this? Do you think it has a future?*

The general idea definitely has a future, if only in the PT Barnum sense. This particular implementation doesn't seem to be anything special - there's nothing in it that grabs me as being a great solution to any of the problems I currently have to deal with. But then, I see thick client apps, especially traditional Delphi 2 tier apps, as quite different from web apps.

I'd be more interested if uniGUI worked the other way, and provided a solid MVC framework for Delphi, then extended that to the web. That way you could more easily have your data + business logic + GUI in three connected pieces, rather than the traditional Delphi/RAD problem that business logic gets all tangled up in the GUI, then the web application is a pain to develop because the layers "have to be" separated. This smells like "solving" that problem by letting you leave the business logic mixed into the GUI when you move to the web.